# Internet explorer 9+ box shadow and jQuery hide()

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, css

I have a strange bug with Internet Explorer 9+ for example an hideable label with a box-shadow :

**CSS**

```
label {
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('label').click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

More complete example on jsFidle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/LaYFE/3/)

Here is the result (2) for those without Internet Explorer :

[image]

So the problem is : If you click the notification to hide it, the shadow remains here on Internet Explorer 9 and 10.

Any clue ?

Comment: set initial display to `inline-block` and not `inline`, and that should solve it.

Comment: Cool, thanks, that was the problem, so Internet Explorer doesn't handle box-shadows on non box elements, fair enough.

Comment: Yes, seems like there are issues with box-shadow on inline elements in IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@adeneo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15774072/internet-explorer-9-box-shadow-and-jquery-hide#comment22423795_15774072) said in the comment the problem is how IE handles `box-shadow` on elements which are `display:inline`.

The solution is to set the element to `inline-block` but be aware that will change the positioning of the element.